# Javascript window.prompt with variable containing backslashes

Tags: javascript, jquery, prompt, backslash

I have a page with hyperlinks (naturally) that are constructed from a SQL table but some of the hyperlinks are actually network resources (i.e. \server\path). For those I set up a jQuery statement to find them and replace those `<a href>` tags with `<a onclick='window.prompt...>` so that the network location will be in the textbox of the prompt then users can copy it and paste it into Windows Explorer. The problem is, all the backslashes are being removed. I know you usually have to escape them with double backslashes I'm not putting the paths in manually, they're coming from the SQL table and I'm putting them into the prompt using a variable. Can anyone tell if there's a solution?

```
else if (($link.length > 0) && ($link.substring(0, 4) != "http")) {
  $('.linktext', $this.closest('tr')).after("<span><a href='#link' onclick='window.prompt(\"This resource is located on a network drive and is not accessible via the web browser. Please copy the link and paste into Windows Explorer.\",\""+$link+"\");'>Text</a></span>");
}
```

The prompt works but the text area will look exactly like this `\serverfolder1folder2file.ext`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just thought of a simple solution that can "escape" the URL values after they've been loaded from SQL. This way I can selectively target what to escape and leave the normal http URL's as they are:

```
else if (($link.length > 0) && ($link.substring(0, 4) != "http")) {
            $linkescaped = $link.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");
            $('.filter', $this.closest('tr')).after("<span><a href='#link' onclick='window.prompt(\"This resource is located on a network drive and is not accessible via the web browser. Please copy the link and paste into Windows Explorer.\",\""+$linkescaped+"\");'></a></span>");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two backslashes instead of one: `\\server\\path`.

A backslash inside JavaScript strings/Regular expressions have the special meaning of being an escape character:

```
var stringWithNewLine = "This
doesn't work"; //Error

var stringWithNewLine = "This\ndoes work"; //Escaped new-line feed.
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer my question. I realize that I need to have two backslashes but the question is how to get them into a string that's being passed from the SQL table. I came up with a solution but thank you for your response.

Comment: If your solution is completely different than my answer, post it as a new reply and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` is your solution.

```
echo mysql_real_escape_string("hello\world");
```

outputs

```
hello\\world
```

So just escape your server values before your pass them back to the client.